# import an image from gallery and set it to an imageview

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-gallery

**I wanted to get an image imported from the gallery and set it to an imageview. I was able to select the image from the gallery but it ain't showing up in my imageview. I have tried some of the related questions but wasn't able to get the result.**

**Questions that I have tried:**

[Picture from gallery to an imageview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22238015/picture-from-gallery-to-an-imageview)

[Picking image from gallery and set to imageview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33011148/picking-image-from-gallery-and-set-to-imageview)

**My code:**

```
 private void pickFromGallery() {
    //Create an Intent with action as ACTION_PICK
    Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    // Sets the type as image/*. This ensures only components of type image are selected
    intent.setType("image/*");
    //We pass an extra array with the accepted mime types. This will ensure only components with these MIME types as targeted.
    String[] mimeTypes = {"image/jpeg", "image/png"};
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES,mimeTypes);
    // Launching the Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_GET_SINGLE_FILE);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data){
    if (data != null && requestCode==RESULT_OK){
        Uri selectedImage=data.getData();
        thumbnailImage.setImageURI(selectedImage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you try debugging your code, if so please add in your question what failed in your code. Eg: the onActivityResult's data is null or data.getData() is null etc. This helps your question get answered faster and your question will become a better resource to help other devs like us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll share what I think should help you far enough. You can refactor to meet your resources.
This will help you get image from both gallery and camera. To crop images, I'd recommend a library like uCrop or edmodo cropper.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private int REQUEST_CAMERA = 0, SELECT_FILE = 1;
    private Button btnSelect;
    private ImageView ivImage;
    private String userChoosenTask;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

btnSelect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSelectPhoto);
        btnSelect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectImage();
            }
        });
        ivImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case Utils.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if(userChoosenTask.equals("Take Photo"))
                        cameraIntent();
                    else if(userChoosenTask.equals("Choose from Library"))
                        galleryIntent();
                } else {
                    //code for deny
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void selectImage() {
        final CharSequence[] items = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Library",
                "Cancel" };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                boolean result=Utils.checkPermission(MainActivity.this);

                if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                    userChoosenTask ="Take Photo";
                    if(result)
                        cameraIntent();

                } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                    userChoosenTask ="Choose from Library";
                    if(result)
                        galleryIntent();

                } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    private void galleryIntent()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);//
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),SELECT_FILE);
    }

    private void cameraIntent()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE)
                onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
            else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
                onCaptureImageResult(data);
        }
    }

    private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);

        File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

        FileOutputStream fo;
        try {
            destination.createNewFile();
            fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fo.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ivImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {

        Bitmap bm=null;
        if (data != null) {
            try {
                bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        ivImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
    }

}
```

Create the Utils class

```
public class Utils {
    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 123;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    public static boolean checkPermission(final Context context)
    {
        int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if(currentAPIVersion>=android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                    alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                    alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
                    alertBuilder.setMessage("External storage permission is necessary");
                    alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
                    alert.show();

                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                }
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The main issue was regarding permission. I debug it but I was not able to get the actual error but after your suggestion, I added the permission code and everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way I've done it:

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri targetUri = data.getData();
        Bitmap bitmap;
        try {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(targetUri));
            targetImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first you need to get image using this intent

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

then you need to override `onActivityResult`

by using this code

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK )
    {
        try {
            this.imgUri = data.getData();
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imgView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }}
```